# Isset in if statement not resolving as aspected

Tags: php, isset

Even though both `$input1` and `$input2` are set variables (`$input1 = 1234532` and `$input2 = abcdef`) the ISSET in below code seems to resolve as false causing the 'else' to execute..

```
if (!isset('$input1' ,('input2'))

{
$Result1 = mysql_query 
(" Select var1, var2, var3
from source
where var1 = '$input1' and var2 = '$input2';
");}

else {

{
$Result1 = mysql_query 
(" Select var1, var2, var3
from source
where var1 = '$input1' or var2 = '$input2';
");}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If `isset()` is passed more than one parameter they need to be a comma separated list. The variables should not be in quotes.

```
if (isset('$input1' ,('input2'))
```

should be:

```
if (isset($input1, $input2))
```

Comment: plus.. shouldn't the check be if(isset()) instead of if(!isset())?

Comment: I've got plenty to spare. If I could, I would. :)

Comment: as in the 'isset' appears false because the 'else' statement is executed. Variables are posted as follows

Comment: Array ( [Input1] => 75240900020 [Input2] => m118083

Comment: Those variables are in an array. Do you know how to access array variables? That's all you need to change in the code I proivided for this to work.